# Azure IoT Hub MQTT failure(Without SDK)

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use Microsoft Azure IOT Hub(`MQTT`) to connect my `Java` client device to IOT Hub(without `SDK`). I created device and `SAS` with `TTL` as required. I am using paho client to connect to IoT Hub. I'm getting below error. `SAS` token I created from IoT Hub Tools with 5 hours of expiry time.

> Not authorized to connect (5)     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:28)
> at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck(ClientState.java:1040)
> at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:151)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Below is the code I'm trying:

```
String deviceId = "mqqdirectdevice1";     
          String brokerUri = "ssl://xxxxx:8883";
          String clientId = deviceId;
          System.out.println( "Connecting to " + brokerUri +" as "+clientId);

          MqttAsyncClient client = null;
          try {           
              String sasToken="SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxxxx.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fmqqdirectdevice1&sig=iJ3jacTNMdyyhIrQueBN5X6uEqURYCKfa5Z63ePKDRs%3D&se=1600335545";
              client = new MqttAsyncClient( brokerUri, clientId,new MemoryPersistence());
              
            if ( client != null ) {             
              MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();                          
              client.setCallback( new AzureCallback() );             
              options.setUserName("xxxxxx.net/mqqdirectdevice1?api-version=2018-06-30");
              options.setPassword(sasToken.toCharArray());
             // options.setPassword(sasToken.toCharArray());
              options.setKeepAliveInterval(230);
              options.setCleanSession(false);
              options.setMqttVersion(4);              
              IMqttToken token=client.connect( options );
              token.waitForCompletion(60 * 1000);
              System.out.println("Sent MQTT CONNECT packet was acknowledged");
              if ( client.isConnected() ) {
                System.out.println( "Success!" );
              } else {
                System.out.println( "Could not connect to Azure IoT hub, timed-out" );
              }
            }
          } catch ( MqttException) {
            //client.getDebug().dumpBaseDebug();
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
            if ( client != null ) {
              try {
                client.disconnect();
              } catch ( MqttException ignore ) {}
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you use the following username:

```
xxxxxx.net/mqqdirectdevice1?api-version=2018-06-30
```

The format is slightly different, you are currently missing a forward slash before the question mark. The correct format is:

```
xxxxxx.net/mqqdirectdevice1/?api-version=2018-06-30
```

I tested it, and the MQTT connection can't be made with the username in an incorrect format.

Comment: Great, happy it works. Please consider marking the answer as 'accepted' to make it easy to find for others.

Comment: It was working file till yesterday, But today i ran into below error Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:197)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:137)
 ... 1 more     Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you make a separate question for this? Looks like that error is unrelated to this question. (This error may occur when two applications connect with the same client id btw)